# GPU (Specifically NVidia) Cloud Computing Centres

Tags: hosting, cloud, cloud-hosting, graphics-processing-unit

In the CPU computing world, you have giant cloud providers like Microsoft Azure, Amazon EC2 and Rackspace. You have also smaller companies that provide dedicated hosting services.

Amazon EC2 has limited support for GPU computing with Tesla, as:

1. They are using an old Tesla
2. They only support that in one centre in US.

Otherwise, they would have been a good choice for me.

> What I am looking for is a GPU hosting provider, located, in order of
>   preference, in:
>
> ```
> 1 - UK
> 2 - West Europe
> 3 - USA
> ```
>
> They should also have modern NVidia Tesla K20 or Tesla K20X GPUs and support
>   Windows hosting and interested in a start up.

Comment: I feel that down voting this question was harsh. I was asking a factual question for providers within a criteria, I wasn't asking for "best" providers or "recommended" providers. If you agree with me then please up vote.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still classed as a shopping question which is off-topic on all StackExchange sites. You're more than welcome to join the [ServerFault chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) but EWWhite's answer below is pretty much all that can be said here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it yourself :)

If you have a good feeling as to your requirements, what precludes you from establishing a co-location footprint and doing this yourself?

Assuming your application stack is compute-heavy and wouldn't necessarily benefit from multiple availability zones or resiliency opportunities afforded by a cloud provider, wouldn't it make sense to provision the hardware *you* want and build the appropriate infrastructure?

But if that's not an option due to scale or cost... 
[**just go with the cloud computing/hosting providers that Nvidia endorses *on their own website***](http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-cloud-computing-services.html).